# How to ensure first iteration of a loop is finished before executing second iteration?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop, automation, cypress

```
cy.document().then(document => {
  const arra = [...document.querySelectorAll('.instances__action')];

  for (let i = 1; i <= arra.length; i++) {
    let state = document.querySelector(
      `#root > section > section > main > div > div > section.instances > div > div > div > div > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(${i}) > td:nth-child(3) > span`
    ).innerText;

    if (state !== 'Finished') {
      document
        .querySelector(
          `#root > section > section > main > div > div > section.instances > div > div > div > div > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(${i}) > td:nth-child(7) > div > button.ant-btn.ant-btn-primary.ant-btn-sm`
        )
        .click();
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }
});
```

here, suppose the `arra.length` is 2. on each iteration button is clicked.
I want to do it one at a time. At first, it should check if the state is `finished` or not.
If the state is `not finished` it should press the button and wait until the state becomes finished.
After that, it should go to the next iteration. In my current implementation, It goes to the second iteration before the first iteration is finished.

Answer (score 1):

At the section of the code that sets the text to `Finished`, have it call the `resolve` function of a Promise constructor which is assigned to in the loop. Then, in the loop, construct the Promise and `await` it. For example:

```
let resolveFn = () => undefined;

// ...
// Run loop:
(async () => {
  // ...
  for ( // ...
  // ...
    if (state !== 'Finished') {
      const prom = new Promise(resolve => resolveFn = resolve);
      document.querySelector(...).click();
      await prom;
    }
}
})();

// ...

function clickHandler() {
  // ...
  // At the point where you assign "Finished", call the resolveFn:
  span.textContent = 'Finished';
  resolveFn();
}
```

If you don't have control over the code that assigns the `Finished` text, the other possibility to watch for the change of the text would be to use a MutationObserver, eg:

```
if (state !== 'Finished') {
  document.querySelector(...);.click();
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    new MutationObserver((_, observer) => {
      if (span.textContent === 'Finished') {
        observer.disconnect();
        resolve();
      }
    })
      .observe(span, { childList: true });
  });
}
```

Comment: I tried your second snippet. but it only executes the first iteration, nothing else. actually it is a cypress test case. The main goal is to click start buttons (which I mapped into an array)
one after another (but ensure that first one is changed into 'finished' state after button is clicked)

https://gist.github.com/ashiqdev/93213ce26494fdbab8478dd722bc30ea

Comment: You didn't copy the code exactly. See the code in the answer using `if (span.textContent === 'Finished') {`, but you have `if (span === 'Finished') {`, which will never be true because `span` is an HTMLElement which is never reassigned, not a string

Comment: well, same thing happens. there are two `requested` state. first one is ran properly.
than I got this error in cypress  `Error: Cypress command timeout of '6000ms' exceeded. (and Mocha's done() called multiple times)`

edited code: https://gist.github.com/ashiqdev/93213ce26494fdbab8478dd722bc30ea

Comment: Sounds like `if (span.innerText === 'Finished') {` is never fulfilled - you should look to the point at which the span's content is assigned to. Or if the span gets removed from the DOM completely, you'll need to re-select it.

Comment: Btw, you should probably [never ever use `innerText`](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/) - use the standard (and more predictable, and faster) `textContent` instead